# Using "data-toggle" with Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html.actionlink

I want to use "data-toggle" wiht actionLink. Like this;

```
 Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Users", "Admin", new { item.UserId , strRole = strRole }, new { id = "cmdDelete", href="#myAlert",  data-toggle="modal" })
```

Unfortunately, doesn't accept. How can i use "data-toggle" like standart links?

Answer (score 87):

You can't. But there is a simple work-around. What you do is, replace the - with a _. During runtime it will get converted to a dash (-). 
So;

```
Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Users", "Admin", new { item.UserId , strRole = strRole }, new { id = "cmdDelete", href="#myAlert",  data_toggle="modal" })
```

Comment: Yes :) MVC 3,5 at least.

Comment: Yes, Worked for me , Thank You

Comment: Brilliant, just what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

```
     @Html.ActionLink("TextLink", "ActionName", new { id = id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", data_toggle = "modal", data_target="#exampleModal" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the action link simply as follows :

```
Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Users", "Admin", new { item.UserId , strRole = strRole }, new { id = "cmdDelete" })
```

then Use Jquery as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cmdDelete').attr('data-target', '#myAlert');
    $('#cmdDelete').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace data-toggle to data_toggle

```
Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Users", "Admin", new { item.UserId , strRole = strRole }, new { id = "cmdDelete", href="#myAlert",  data_toggle="modal" })
```