# @Url.Action does not route when clicked in the navbar

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I do not possess much knowledge on `MVC`, `JavaScript` or `Bootstrap`. But here I am stuck at something working on all the three. I have a `Layout` page consisting of a navigation bar styled using `Bootstrap`. Idea taken from [here](https://codepen.io/wizly/pen/BlKxo). Markup given below.

```
<div id="innerTab">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "Home ")" data-toggle="tab">Index</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="@Url.Action(" About ", "Home ")" data-toggle="tab">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane active">
      @RenderBody()
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since this is a `Layout View`, I want to be able to load the content from the other Views in the tab content area. Due to which, I have to make use of `@RenderBody()` which cannot be called more than once. I am not really sure what `data-toggle` does exactly but clicking on `About` had no impact whatsoever. Then I realised that I had to manually set the `active` class on the clicked tab via `JS`. So this is what I did.

```
$(".nav li").on("click", function() {
  $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).tab('show');
})
```

Now, the selected tab did become active. However, for some unknown reason, when clicked on `About`, it does not navigate to the `About` page but stays at `Index`. Because of which I had to change it to `@Html.ActionLink` as given below.

```
@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")
```

This successfully navigated to the `About` page. However, the `About` tab becomes active for a second and quickly switches to the `Index` tab but displays the content from the `About` page. like below.

[image]

Thought adding `data-toggle` would fix this. So I followed the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976120/using-data-toggle-with-html-actionlink#).

```
@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { data_toggle="tab"})
```

And then it's back to square one. Except for the fact that it highlights the tab I select, it does nothing.I am lost!! Where am I going wrong?

Comment: First remove Bootstrap's javascript and css -- it will look bad but forget about that for now. Does the navigation load the page that you'd expect? Next, read about [Bootstrap's nav](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav) component then reintroduce the javascript and css. The nav component should work without custom script.

Comment: @Jasen removing Bootstrap enables navigation without any problems!! So the issue was with the way I handled the Bootstrap CSS then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `@Url.Action(" Index ", "Home ")` isn't working because you have extra spaces around your `Action` and `Controller` arguments.

It should be `@Url.Action("Index", "Home")`

---

*"The About tab becomes active for a second and quickly switches to the Index"*

That's because, on click, jQuery click event adds a class. But MVC redirects to a new page and the `_Layout` is rendered again with the default `active` tab `Home`.

So to the top of your `About.cshtml`,

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
    ViewBag.ActiveNav = "About"; // you'll need to add this to Home as well
}
```

Then change the Layout to:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">

   //Based on the "ActiveNav" value, "active" class will be added

    <li class="@(ViewBag.ActiveNav == "Home" ? "active" : "")">
      @Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "Home")
    </li>
    <li class="@(ViewBag.ActiveNav == "About" ? "active" : "")">
      @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Now the `active` class is added to particular `li`, based on the page.

Comment: I knew the issue was with the class being reset on new page rendering!! Just didn't know how to fix it. This works like a charm!! Dhanyawadagalu!! :)